# Tabview not updating with provider when switching between 2 tabs

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a provider to update my widget, but it doesn't update when I switch tab. Am I using it wrongly?

charts.dart

```
Widget chart(BuildContext context, ChartType chartType) {
  return FutureBuilder<void>(
    future: Provider.of<ChartModel>(context, listen: false).loadChartHabits(),
    builder: (context, data) => Container(
      Text(data);
    );
  );
}


class Charts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              <Tab>[
                Tab(text: Constants.weekly),
                Tab(text: Constants.monthly),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
               chart(context, ChartType.Weekly),
               chart(context, ChartType.Monthly),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also did add this in main.dart

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TodayModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChartModel()),
      ],
```

Update: It works after I placed a loadchart but is this the correct way to load data than needs await? I need to wait for the data to come back.

```
    appBar: TabBar(
              tabs: <Tab>[
                Tab(text: Constants.weekly),
                Tab(text: Constants.monthly),
              ],
              onTap: (value) {
                Provider.of<ChartModel>(context, listen: false).loadChart(ChartType.values[value]);
              },
            ),
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a solution, I posted it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099852/changing-tab-does-not-rebuild-list/67169859#67169859

Answer (score 0):

instead of FutureBuilder you should use Consumer

```
 return  Consumer<ChartModel>(
          builder: (_, provider, __) {
            return Container(child:Text(provider.data));
              
           
          },
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will fit your particular case, because mine was a little bit m ore complicated. I solved by adding a state to the FutureBuilder, so, while changing tabs and setting the state, it would also update the state of the widgets inside the tabs. I'm not sure that the explanation is correct, but it did work in my case.

You should try changing your code like this:

```
Widget chart(BuildContext context, ChartType chartType) {
  return StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, setState) {
       return FutureBuilder(
         future: Provider.of<ChartModel>(context, listen: false).loadChartHabits(),
         builder: (context, data) => Container(Text(data));
       );
    }
  );
}
```