# Changing tab does not rebuild list

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have two tabs using a `TabBar`.

In each tab a list of items is displayed from FireStore database - **this is the same list of items only with different filter applied.**

The list is obtained from the DB using `Provider` :

```
List<Item> userItems =
        Provider.of<List<Item>>(context, listen: true) ?? [];
```

The list is filtered on each tab using `retainWhere` :

**Tab 1 Filter**

```
     userItems.retainWhere(
      (item) =>
          item.usedDate == null &&
          item.isActive != true,
    );
```

**Tab 2 Filter**

```
     userItems.retainWhere(
      (item) =>
          item.usedDate == null &&
          item.isActive == true,
    );
```

The problem is the list filters out all items when moving to either tab. It seems to be filtering the already filtered list, rather than filtering it from scratch. Even though each tab is its own `Stateful` widget function and builds from scratch each time.

It is not cacheing data, my `print` statements show it is building each list every time I change tabs, but still it does not work.

I can't work out why this is happening.

Comment: Please consider put your code about `TabBar` and `List` on your question too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating two separate lists, rather than just one with different filters applied.

```
 List<Item> allUserItems =
        Provider.of<List<Item>>(context, listen: true) ?? [];

    List<Item> userItems1 = allUserItems.where(
      (item) {
        return item.usedDate == null &&
          item.isActive != true,
      },
    ).toList();


    List<Item> userItems2 = allUserItems.where(
      (item) {
        return item.usedDate == null &&
          item.isActive == true,
      },
    ).toList();
```

I then passed each list to the respective tab widget.

I am not sure why filtering a single list does not work, possibly something to do with `TabBar`.